# Node.js __dirname not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

My directory look like this:

> /config.json , /server.js , /staticFiles/welcome.html

Running server.js gives error:

> app.use(express.static(_dirname + "/staticFiles"));
>    ^   ReferenceError: _dirname is not defined

My Server.js:

```
//------------Server-------------

var fs = require("fs");
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config.json"));

 console.log("Server UP and running.."); 

 var host = config.host;
 var port = config.port;
 var express = require("express");

 var app = express.createServer();



 //---------Application----------------

app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(_dirname + "/staticFiles"));

app.get("/", function(request,response){

response.send("<h1>"/" of TrimServer</h1>");

 });

app.listen(port,host); 
console.log("Listening on Port -->",port);


 //--------------End-------------------
```

Comment: A quick search found multiple matches for this error. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/nodejs/K4vhAC5yXm4/qFfGK0WCgSYJ

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are using one underscore while this variable actually has two underscores at the beginning:
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

So use

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/staticFiles"));
```

instead of

```
app.use(express.static(_dirname + "/staticFiles"));
```

Comment: Thanks Cromax. @ManishS, you may mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

use __dirname instead of _dirname (Missing one underscore in your code)

Answer (score 0):

Use `__dirname` instead of `_dirname` (You are missing one underscore in your code).